# Submit Form Page

Tags: visualforce

We need to create a page in the Salesforce application, which will do the following things: page contains submit form, on submit event it should call external API. Depends on API response page should show success or error message. No data should be saved in salesforce database.
Could you please advise what mechanism should we use: pages, layouts, etc... I am very new with salesforce so I am looking for ANY help.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you describe the external API part in more detail? For example is it SOAP or REST/JSON and is authentication involved? You can write a Visualforce page with a custom Apex controller that accepts user input (without storing in the salesforce database) and forwards it to an external service and displays the response (providing the response comes back within a few seconds). But there is quite a learning curve to overcome.

Comment: Thank you Keith, your comment was very helpful. I already managed to create custom controller and custom page. Do you have any link with example how to submit two values from apex:form to external URL (kind of 3-d party site) and show response at the page? Thank you in advance.

Comment: PS: I need a form with inputs which IS NOT associated with any Object.

Comment: @Vladimir I am confused why you need this to be Salesforce at all.  It just seems like it's a simple AJAX call, and the API may even publish a JavaScript toolkit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a contrived example of a controller that makes a request to the Bing search engine:

```
public with sharing class DemoController {

    public String text {get; set;}
    public String html {get; set;}

    public DemoController() {
        text = 'adele hello';
    }

    public PageReference search() {

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://www.bing.com/search?q='
                + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(text, 'UTF-8'));
        req.setMethod('GET');

        HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
        html = res.getBody();

        return null;
    }
}
```

and just dumps the resulting response HTML back into the same page:

```
<apex:page controller="DemoController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageMessages/>
        <apex:sectionHeader title="Demo"/>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!search}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Search">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Text"/>
                    <apex:inputText value="{!text}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Result">
                <apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!html}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The first time you run it you will be receive an error message that explains that you need to allow access to that remote site - just follow the instructions that are presented. Thereafter the page should just work.

Unlike Bing, many external APIs do require authentication which adds complexity.

Comment: Is a POST request also possible using this approach? I have a similar requirement, but instead of a GET request, we need to POST the information to an external website?